# Spliting and Deleteing Values in a Field, Python

Tags: python, split

I'm trying to fix the values in a field in an access table. The values look like this

```
G45-f1
C43-m1
C6-h1
M90_N9-h1
K9_Y7-h2
```

I want to slice away everything before the dash "-" and delete the rest, to look like this:

```
G45
C43
C6
M90_N9
K9_Y7
```

I know I can split the values at the dash `x.split("-")`, but I'm not sure how to delete the remainder.  Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str.split()` always returns a list with at least one element, just select the first element of the result to ignore the rest:

```
x.split('-')[0]
```

You may want to limit the split count, since you are discarding everything but the first part anyway:

```
x.split('-', 1)[0]
```

Comment: Indexing. right. I should have figured that out. On a tight timeline. Thanks for your quick reply :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.split`, but you can also use `str.partition` which only splits to the first occurence and is always guaranteed to return a 3-tuple... (*head*, *delimiter*, *tail*):

```
>>> print 'M90_N9-h1'.partition('-')[0]
M90_N9
```

This has the advantage that should you want *tail*, then even if the delimiter is not present it will be an empty string, rather than an `IndexError` exception via `str.split`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new list

```
newlist = [x.split('-')[0] for x in oldlist]
```